# How to remove BTRFS subvolumes used by docker?

Tags: btrfs

I was playing with docker and then I found with btrfs list many docker subvolumes like this one:

```
ID 23305 gen 3405505 top level 22147 path var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/1464e922.....
```

I do not use docker. How to get rid off of these subvolumes? There is too many to just delete it one by one... Thanks

Comment: You can change Docker's storage driver to `overlay2` to prevent this from happening. That's the driver that Docker will (usually) use if `/var/lib/docker` is not on a btrfs filesystem.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo su
cd /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes
ls /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes | xargs btrfs subvolume delete
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working on Fedora 38. Seems Docker always left the subvolume without any explanation. It's sucks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Docker leaves these lying around even though the images and volumes have been removed, ask docker to clean them up:

```
docker system prune
```

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9939